# Keeping the cursor on the textbox after pressing Enter button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vuejs3

I wanted a small help in VUEJS.
I have a form and i have a text box. When clicking the enter button its gives me some result and clears the text box but the blinking cursor doesn't come back to the text box.
Any idea on how to achieve it ->

```
1. I write some text in the text box
2. Presses Enter 
3. Provides some info and clears the text box
4. Same text box starts to blink and i need to be able to write something back again
```

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container app-card">
    <div class="app-content">
          <b-form-input-with-validation
            v-model="number"
            :rules="{max: 255, required: true}"
            label="number"
            name="number"
            type="text"
            @keyup.enter="onSubmitClick"
            ref="track"
          />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {

    methods: {
     
      reset() {
        this.innerValue.tracking_number = null
      },

      async onSubmitClick() {
        this.$refs.track.focus()
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        track: null,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I am getting this error:

```
this.$refs.track.focus is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs) on the textbox so you can focus it from the clear method.

#### Options API (with `<b-form-input>`)

```html
<b-form-input v-model="number" ref="refText"></b-form-input>
```

```js
methods: {
 clear() {
    this.$refs.refText.focus();
  }
}
```

#### Composition API (with regular `<input>`)

```html
<input ref="refText" />
```

```js
setup() {
  const refText = ref(null);
}
```

```js
const clear = function() {
   refText.value.focus();
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const mytext = ref('press button to clear me');
    const refText = ref(null);
    
    const clear = function() {
      mytext.value = '';
      refText.value.focus();
    }

    return {
      mytext,
      refText,
      clear
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="mytext" ref="refText" />
  <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Comment: i have update the code and i am getting some error message.

Comment: Not going to work on a custom component.  This is why you should always show code in your question.  You didn't mention or show Bootstrap Vue or a custom component, and you're using the options API.

Comment: Use a regular `<b-form-input>` and it will work

Comment: Sure, as you can see in the demo it does work indeed.  Do you need to see it with a `<b-form-input>` for some reason?

Comment: yes, need to see it in ```<b-form-input>```

Comment: Hi, @dan thanks alot for the help. this link: ```jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/buec0k26 ``` helped to sort this to certain extent.